# Do the indices of List get updated after doing List.subList.Clear()?

Tags: java, list, sublist

I know that for some `List list;` doing `list.subList(i,j).Clear()` clears `list` items. But do the indices of `list` get updated accordingly? I think it is very useless if not. If yes, what is the overhead of doing so? Especially since we need to delete the range, and then advance the indices. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The overhead of doing so is entirely dependent on the `List` implementation you're using.

Answer (score 1):

The indexes are updated for such operations.